# How to get Label to show on top left of a view in stackView?

Tags: swift, uikit

[image]

I want the "Reviews" text to show up in the top left of the third view in stackView (view with select button).

I tried to set top anchor of the label to the top-anchor of the view and am having it show up outside of the third view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make @IBOutlet of thirdView`@IBOutlet weak var thirdView: UIView!`

Add `reviewsBoxLabel` in `thirdView`

Replace `setupBottomLabelConstraints` with:

```
func setupBottomLabelConstraints() {
    thirdView.addSubview(reviewsBoxLabel)
    reviewsBoxLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=fals
    reviewsBoxLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:thirdView.topAnchor).isActive=true
    reviewsBoxLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo:thirdView.leftAnchor).isActive=true 
}
```